# How to sendvalue into date field using selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

Using SendKeys method , date field is not taking the input. Have tried by clicking on the field and sending value. But still it fails

```
IwebElement StartDate = driver.findElement(By.name("inpR8C3L8"));
StartDate.click();
Startdate.sendkeys("010119");
```

Here is the html:

```
<input type="text" class="wpsEditField" style="color: green;" size="8" maxlength="8" name="inpR8C3L8" value=" 0/00/00" tabindex="101" onfocus="javascript: iwaJSR168_5250SetCurrentInputField(this);">
```

how can i achieve this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IJavascriptExecutor to sendtext to your element using javascript.

```
IJavascriptExecutor jse = (IJavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='010119';",StartDate);
```

where argument[0] is element.